# How to position my images at the end line of the header in responsive way?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website page, that should be responsive for both desktop and mobile browsers.

I have a header,  gave it a height of 60 vh, and I have 3 images that should be positioned horizontally at the end line of the header.

I used `position: relative;` to position the images with a space between them 3%.

The problem begins when testing the responsiveness on mobile and tablet screens, I find my images above the end line of the header which means that the images are in the wrong place "vertically".

**PS**: My images in both cases are aligned horizontally in right way

I want to stick the images to the end line of the header in all screens like this:
[image: Image 1]

But instead I get that in non-desktop screens:

[image: Image 2]

**This is my code**

**HTML**

```
   <header class="header">
      <div class="sup-header"><span>gtd.</span></div>
      <div class="welcome-msg"><h1>Hello, we're gtd.</h1></div>

      <div class="sub-header">  
        <div class="sub-header-imgs">
          <img src="media/img_lisa_circle.png" class="sub-header-img">
          <img src="media/img_danielle_circle.png" class="sub-header-img">
          <img src="media/img_brian_circle.png" class="sub-header-img">
        </div>
     </div>
   </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  background: url('../media/img_hero.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 80%;
}

.sub-header {
  position: relative;
  top: 36%;
}

.sub-header-imgs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.sub-header-img {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  margin: 0 3%;
}
```

**So why images position vertically not responsive and moving upward in small screens instead of keeping in the middle of end line of the header?? and how to fix that??**

Comment: Use a **bottom** value instead of **top: 36%**. Should fix your problem.

Comment: @Quentin Veron No, it did not

Comment: Could you make a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @SaherElgendy can't see de image.

Comment: @azeós
this should work
https://i.imgur.com/aIxYwnW.png

Comment: @azeós

This what i get in smaller screens

https://i.imgur.com/CtZ230T.png

Comment: You might want to look into the wonders of `display: flex`, aka "flexbox". It handles things like this wonderfully.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey

ok can you show me how to achieve that by code, please

Comment: Please do some research and try it yourself; you'll learn a lot more than being spoonfed the answer.

Comment: Thanks i just asked you that because i think that flexbox is not applied in this case, yes i can use flexbox to align some elements horizontally and vertically in responsive way, but my question here is different, i know how to use flexbox very well, but this example is somehow stubborn, please try to understand  my question!! @Heretic Monkey